# Will reflective aluminum on windows reduce solar heat transmission?

Tags: insulation

My room get overheated by the evening sun. I have some blinds but its not really helping. I was wondering if putting some [reflective insulation](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Reflectix-48-in-x-25-ft-Double-Reflective-Insulation-Roll-BP48025/100052556) would help. Not removing the blinds but between the blinds and the glass.

The room is on 2nd floor so would prefer a solution that doesnt need outside modifications. Secondly, would prefer a medium term solution that I can possibly easily remove when I move.

Thoughts? Feedback? Anything I should be worried about? Less concerned that it might not look great from the outside - but if it keeps the room cooler, I would be happy. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This stuff will definitely help but could also cause overheating and cracking of the glass. Perhaps white foam insulation boards instead; easily placed and removed...

Comment: Is there anything you could add to the outside?

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/7893/95658

Comment: Do you have shutters? Close em...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it had a silly question about cracking glass - arent these safe for car windshields? is that because that glass i harder than regular window glass?

Comment: There is UV reflective window film that can be applied inside which cuts down on heat transmission. Tinted or not.

Comment: [Reflective window film](https://activewindowfilms.co.uk/58-mirror-silver-privacy-one-way-pro-window-tinting-tint-film-solar-control-sticky-back-51-76-100-152cm.html) is the way to go. It's not UV reflective though, but IR (heat) reflective. Glass blocks UV, anyway.

Comment: @smk, I had a silver foil-backed sunshade to shade my truck windshield from the inside and it caused (at least, I believe it caused...) my windshield to crack. I was parked in direct sun in the American southwest and the temperatures were over 110°F and the windows were up, so I am perhaps to blame. And I don't have evidence that it caused the crack...